# Why does async.filter() not accept an error?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

The docs for [async.filter()](https://github.com/caolan/async#filter) say the iterator callback does NOT accept an error, apparently "in line with the way node libraries work with truth tests like `fs.exists`".

I don't understand that explanation at all. Why can't it accept errors? What if my asynchronous truth test involves doing something that might result in error sometimes?

Example: I have an array of path names that could be a mixture of files or directories. I want to filter out the directories, so I use `async.filter` with an iterator that calls `fs.stat` on them, and then calls `done(stat.isFile());`. But what if my `fs.stat` hits an ENOENT error for one of the paths? What do I do with that error?

Comment: I guess the author leaves that up to you to decide whether that item with error is in the filtered result or not.

Answer (score 1):

The `async.filter()` method, just like the `.some()` and `.every()` methods, are merely checking for `true` or `false` against each item in the array. These is not meant for control-flow to catch errors, and potentially not meant for large processing at each step. The author of `async` leaves that up to you though, and if one of your checks throws an error, that could be interpreted as a `false`.

An alternative for you, if you require every path name to be valid, would be `.each()`

```
var filteredArray = [];
async.each( paths, function( path, eachCb ){
  //some asynchronous check you define
  checkpath( path, function( err ) {
    if( err ) return eachCb( err );
    filteredArray.push( path );
    eachCb( null );
  } );
}, function( eachErr ) {
    if( eachErr ) {
      console.log( "Not all paths were correct. " + eachErr.message );
      //other stuff here, perhaps a callback with this error message
    }
    else {
      //success!
      //filteredArray now filled with only valid paths, and only get here if no errors.
    }
} );
```

Comment: I still don't get why it is designed differently from other methods. I know it's for checking true/false for each item. But what if the process of establishing true/false encounters an error? Take the synchronous equivalent... If your regular synchronous filter function calls fs.statSync, that might throw an error. Maybe you wrap your whole `arr.filter(...)` in a `try` block and catch it. (continued below)

Comment: async usually provides a way of doing the same thing – if an error occurs during one of the iterators, there's a way for you to sort of "catch" it in the original stack (as long as the iterator passes it to `done`). I still don't get why this should be any different for `filter`.

Comment: If your iterator encounters an error, you can't just throw it, as you won't get a useful stack trace, that's why async usually lets you pass it to done. I don't see why the fact that it's "merely checking for true or false" has any bearing on whether I might want to be able to handle errors coming from an iterator. By the same logic, it should be impossible to throw an error from an `Array.prototype.filter` iterator.

Comment: You might want to contact the author about this : ) In general, and IMO, I think these methods are for quick checks. Have an array of numbers and want to filter out all the odd numbers? That's the simple true/false check. The nice part of how these are designed is _they will always return true or false_. You can handle an error, but an error won't short-circuit the array processing. To use the `.filter()` methods as designed, and if you wish to check for errors in your logic, you should pre-process the input array, then apply the filter. Or use `.each()` and title your method 'filter' : )